# Assigned variable follows the changes of array unexpectedly

Tags: javascript

I assign the new variable to an array. after modifying the array the assigned variable follows the changes of array unexpectedly!

```js
let reference = "I was sent* to Earth,* to protect you."

let orders = reference.split("*").map(s => s.toLowerCase().replace(/\,|\?|\!|\:|\./g,'').trim());

let answer = orders;

console.log(orders)
console.log(answer)
// changing orders and not answer!
orders.push(orders.shift());

// the orders changes as expected but the answer (that is not changed before follows the orders changes)
console.log(orders)
console.log(answer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let answer = orders;
```

You are copying reference of orders to answer as it is an array.

It's like giving another name to the same array(block of memory).

```
This should solve your problem
```

Change `let answer = orders;` to `let answer = [...orders];`

```js
let reference = "I was sent* to Earth,* to protect you."

let orders = reference.split("*").map(s => s.toLowerCase().replace(/\,|\?|\!|\:|\./g,'').trim());

let answer = [...orders];

console.log(orders)
console.log(answer)
// changing orders and not answer!
orders.push(orders.shift());

// the orders changes as expected but the answer (that is not changed before follows the orders changes)
console.log(orders)
console.log(answer)
```

Comment: What if I assign a variable to another variable (none of them is an array); like `let var1 = var2`

Comment: Then only the value is copied.

Comment: The variable that holds an array actually holds a reference to the memory location

Comment: If you were to do var a = arr[0] still only value is copied

Answer (score 1):

`let answer = orders.slice(0)` will make a shallow copy of your array object.
in my opinion, to copy your array object the solution is:

```
let answer = copy(orders);

// copy function
function copy(object) {
    var output, value, key;
    output = Array.isArray(object) ? [] : {};
    for (key in object) {
        value = object[key];
        output[key] = (typeof value === "object") ? copy(value) : value;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mutating the existing array. Clone it by doing the following:

```js
let reference = "I was sent* to Earth,* to protect you."

let orders = reference.split("*").map(s => s.toLowerCase().replace(/\,|\?|\!|\:|\./g,'').trim());

let answer = [...orders];

console.log(orders)
console.log(answer)
// changing orders and not answer!
orders.push(orders.shift());

// the orders changes as expected but the answer (that is not changed before follows the orders changes)
console.log(orders)
console.log(answer)
```

Alternatively, you can use `let answer = orders.slice(0)` if you're not using es6

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue.

```
let answer = [...orders];
```